# Disable RadioButton inside Repeater Item

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I have the following Repeater which contains a radio button:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptLeaveRequests" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="RptLeaveRequests_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table id="tableItem" runat="server">
    //displaying other data which is not relevant to qeustion
                <td style="50px">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now data is being populated from the method in the code:

```
DataTable dt = new LeaveLogic().GetManagerUnverifiedLeaveRequests(Convert.ToInt32(Context.User.Identity.Name));
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    RptLeaveRequests.DataSource = dt;
                    RptLeaveRequests.DataBind();
                }
```

how can loop through each row and disable/hide radio buttons if a record retrieved from the database (and DataTable dt) called `ReadOnly` is true?

Should this be placed in the `Repeater_ItemDataBound` method or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtVerified" runat="server" Enabled='<%#Eval("booleanValue") %>' >
```

But you need to make sure that you are binding the radio button list with boolean value.